# manipulating what the pointer is pointing at

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

This is probably a really easy question but I can not seem to find an explicit answer online. Say a had a pointer to an array declared as:

static char newMessage[400];
    char *p = &newMessage;

(I don't know if this is right) How would I go about manipulation the newMessage array using only the pointer. I am doing this because a C cannot return an array but can return a pointer to an array. please be gentle, I'm new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is *almost* right; the only problem is that you have mismatched pointer types.  You want:

```
char *p = newMessage;
```

Not:

```
char *p = &newMessage;
```

The latter tries to initialize `p`, a `char *` variable, with a value of type `char (*)[400]`, which isn't valid C.

After you've created and initialized `p`, you can just use it however you'd like:

```
p[6] = 12;
```

Or something like that.

Comment: That made my code compile with no warnings finally, now i just have to deal with the seg fault error i'm getting:D

Comment: @OP- With this approach, the code using the returned pointer just has to manually remember that it points to 400 bytes of allocated space. This is a bit fragile and is the sort of thing that leads to bugs down the track,  so take care.

Answer (score 2):

Just point the pointer to the array

```
char* p = newMessage ;
```

And return it from a function.

You use it the same as you would use the array it points to.

```
newMessage[2] = '\0'
p[2] = '\0'
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare an array like `static char newMessage[400]`, the identifier `newMessage` is substituted by **the address of the first element** of the array, and it behaves like a pointer.

```
char* p= newMessage;
char* q= "Hi, world";
newMessage[4]= 'x';
p[4]= 'x';
*(newMessage + 2)= 0;
*(p+2)= 0;
strlen(newMessage);
strlen(q);
strcmp(newMessage, "Hi world");
strcmp(p, q);
```

are all valid expressions.

Note that in the last four function calls, you are not passing arrays, but pointers to the first character of the string. And by convention, the functions scan the memory until they find a null byte terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it should be `char *p = newMessage;` .The `char[]` behaves similar to `char*`. 
You'll later modify it by how you usually modify any pointer.
BTW, this is very basic so it's better you read a tutorial.
Also, since you asked this, if you're planning to return a pointer to the array, the array better not be allocated on the stack. It should be heap-allocated (it's in your case since static)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually manipulate the array, as arrays are no first class type in c.

Almost anything you care to do with the array name, will make it degenerate to a pointer. The exception being `sizeof`, so you can get the element count using `sizeof array/sizeof *array`.

What you can do, is change the values of the array elements. Use pointer arithmetic and dereferencing `*`. The index operator `a[b]` is syntactic sugar for `*(a+b)`.

Also, you can use library functions (or your own), which accept pointers.